# jQuery Validate I would like to add a scroll up slow to error

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-validate

I would like to add a slow scroll up to the top error on the form, just not sure how to implement it on this script. I have tried a few other peoples suggestions but being new to this could not get it to work. Thanks

```
  $(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#frmFormMail").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            field_0: { // Title
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_1: { // Full Name
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field_2: { // Address
                required: true,
                minlength: 20
            },
            field_3: { // Age
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            field_4: { // Marital Status
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_5: { // Children
                required: true,
                minlength: 1
            },
            field_6: { // Nationality
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_7: { // Health
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            field_8: { // Glasses
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_9: { // Car Licence
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            field_10: { // Nationality
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_11: { // Website of interest 1
                required: false,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field_12: { // Website of interest 2
                required: false,
                minlength: 5
            },
            field_13: { // Applying for Position
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_14: { // Resume
                required: true
            },
            field_15: { // Cv
                required: true
            },
            field_16: { // Present Job
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            },
            field_17: { // When can You Start
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },
            field_18: { // Relocate Dropdown
                required: true // required: false not a required field, required: true required field
            },
            field_19: { // Last 3 Jobs
                required: true,
                minlength: 30
            },
            field_20: { // Attach Reference
                required: false
            },
            field_21: { // Attach Other of interest
                required: false
            },
            field_22: { // Sutible for this job
                required: true,
                minlength: 100
            },
            field_23: { // Sutible for this job
                required: true,
                minlength: 100
            },
            field_24: { // Comments questions
                required: false,
                minlength: 50
            },

        },
// Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            field_14: {
                required: "This field is required - will validate on submit"
            },
            field_15: {
                required: "This field is required - will validate on submit"
            },
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

  });
```

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? Like do you have the script to check if there is an error or not, where is the part where you add them etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it can be implemented using `jquery validator's invalidHandler` callback 
From the jquery Validator  [Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/),

```
invalidHandler

Type: Function()
Callback for custom code when an invalid form is submitted.
```

Called with an event object as the first argument, and the validator as the second.

So your code can be incorporated like the below eg,

```
$("#frmFormMail").validate({

  invalidHandler : function() {
       $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#frmFormMail").offset().top // scroll top to your form on error
        }, 2000);
   }

});
```

<kbd>[**inValidHandler reference**](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-validate-invalidhandler-question)</kbd>

Comment: Yes this seem to be the kind of thing I need, only that it stops the form validation?

Comment: Nope, just go through the documentation. It just an handler on error ecounter